# Are the changes done by db command in MongoDB permanent and how?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Are the changes done using the shell in mongodb permanent ?
And how MongoDb detects the config file?

I am stuck in setting Slow query logs in MongoDb.
We have a command `db.setProfilingLevel()` to set profiling level.
But how can we set profiling for all databases and how to set it via Config file?

How mongodb remember this change after restart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Changes made to data in MongoDB shell are permanent but for configuration parameters, they will last only till next restart of instance if they are not specified in config file.

MongoDB runs with default values if config file is not specified.
You can specify config file as,

```
mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf 
or 
mongod --f /etc/mongod.conf
```

and for profiling you can provide parameters from command line or in config file like,

From command line,

```
mongod --slowms <value in milliseconds for slow queries> 
or
mongod --profile <0/1/2>
```

In config file,

```
profile = <0/1/2>
slowms = <value>
logpath = <path>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution..
but is the profile option set in config file is for all databases ?
and how to check the slow queries per database ?

Comment: Yes, Config file is for DB instance and not for single database. Slow queries falling above --slowms <> value will be logged in mongo log file which/whose location again can be specified either from command line or in config file. Check answer now.

Comment: @AmanAggarwal Just to clarify on the clear points already made here.  The practice here is to have a "lagging" member of a ["replica set](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/replication/) where one member (or maybe a couple) do not immediately process the updates submitted. You generally want **most** members of a Replica Set ( or at least the valid failover options ) to be "up to date" with all operations. Then use the "lagging" member(s) as "fallback" points for possible "rollback" sources or other "backup" needs.